# Is there anything in the rules giving Loxodons disadvantage on Stealth checks?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, races, stealth, advantage-and-disadvantage

I'm curious if there is a ruling on this topic. Specifically the debate was over whether a Loxodon Way of the Shadow Monk could benefit from the massive stealth advantages and ninja-teleportation. This would apply equally I presume for Centaurs and other larger (but still medium) playable races.

Speaking of "flavor" it seems a Loxodon/Centaur ninja would be highly ineffective. A 7ft tall 400lb elephant probably wouldn't make a great ninja, right? It makes sense from a world concept level.

But is there actually anything in the rules that would give these large (but still Medium-sized) creatures disadvantage on Stealth checks?

Comment: Tigers are up to 12 feet and weigh 800lb and they have massive stealth advantages

Comment: If you've never seen a Loxodon Ninja, is it because they are *really good at stealth*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no hard rules associating a creature's size with their ability to sneak in this way. Mechanically, the Loxodon is as capable of learning the art of stealth as any race.

The fifth edition of DnD does allow for a way for GM to introduce "common sense" elements into difficulty: advantage and disadvantage. Having one's ankles chained together would be a good example of a reason why a GM'd give disadvantage.

However, introducing a permanent disadvantage for a skill the character uses a lot --- stealth in this case --- is in bad taste if the player was not aware of the penalty in advance. How you want to apply this kind of realism in the table is your choice as a group, so talk with your players if you have a problem with it.

Answer (score 12):

## No, but they won't be able to hide as often.

There is nothing giving loxodon or centaur players a straight disadvantage at stealth check. Actually, size doesn't even affect Dexterity(Stealth) ability checks at all. When rolling to hide, a Gargantuan Gold Dragon has better chances than a Tiny Cat.

It does not mean that they have the same chances to crawl unnoticed behind your sofa, though ; this is covered by the ["hiding" rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Initiative) :

> HIDING
>
> The DM decides when circumstances are appropriate for hiding.

Obviously, a loxodon or centaur will have much more trouble finding an appropriate hiding spot than, say, a human or a dwarf. The DM may use disadvantage at stealth, or advantage at perception, to solve this kind of situation - but he also may decide you can't hide at all.

On the other hand... It may be worth it - as once you hit level 11 and can turn invisible in shadows... There's much fun to be had. I guess the look on your opponent's face, when you reveal yourself, should be priceless.

Comment: Exactly this. To hide, you have to have a hiding spot.

Comment: So long as you can find a shadow big enough!